# WCF JSON missunderstand

Tags: android, json, wcf, retrofit

I am sending requests from my Android phone using retrofit to a server. Result is 200 OK, but I get the next problem: I don't understand 1 type of 1 element here in JSON response body.

```
{
    "Articles":[{
        "Categories":[{
            "Identifier":2147483647,
            "Name":"String content"
        }],
        "Contents":[{
            "URL":"String content"
        }],
        "Country":{
            "Identifier":2147483647,
            "Name":"String content"
        },
        "Description":"String content",
        "ExpiryDate":"\/Date(928146000000+0100)\/",
        "ExtraFields":[{
            "Name":"String content",
            "Value":{
                "Identifier":2147483647,
                "Type":"String content",
                "Value":"String content"
            }
        }],
        "Identifier":2147483647,
        "ImageURL":"String content",
        "Name":"String content",
        "Newsbite":true,
        "PortalID":2147483647,
        "PublishDate":"\/Date(928146000000+0100)\/",
        "Region":{
            "Identifier":2147483647,
            "Name":"String content"
        },
        "Related":[{
            "Categories":[{
                "Identifier":2147483647,
                "Name":"String content"
            }],
            "Contents":[{
                "URL":"String content"
            }],
            "Country":{
                "Identifier":2147483647,
                "Name":"String content"
            },
            "Description":"String content",
            "ExpiryDate":"\/Date(928146000000+0100)\/",
            "ExtraFields":[{
                "Name":"String content",
                "Value":{
                    "Identifier":2147483647,
                    "Type":"String content",
                    "Value":"String content"
                }
            }],
            "Identifier":2147483647,
            "ImageURL":"String content",
            "Name":"String content",
            "Newsbite":true,
            "PortalID":2147483647,
            "PublishDate":"\/Date(928146000000+0100)\/",
            "Region":{
                "Identifier":2147483647,
                "Name":"String content"
            },
            "Related":[null],
            "ShareURL":"String content",
            "Tags":[{
                "Identifier":2147483647,
                "Name":"String content"
            }],
            "Type":2147483647
        }],
        "ShareURL":"String content",
        "Tags":[{
            "Identifier":2147483647,
            "Name":"String content"
        }],
        "Type":2147483647
    }],
    "PageSpecification":{
        "Skipped":2147483647,
        "Taken":2147483647,
        "Total":2147483647
    }
}
```

1st "Related" at the beginning i understood, but 2nd after Region I didn't get what type it is. Any ideas what means this "Related":[null] and how to declare it in JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[]` means the content is a `List`.

`[null]` means this is a `List` containing a `null` value

Comment: So how should i define this list ?

Comment: @ask110593 I don't understand what do you mean by "how" - that's how you define a list. What are you trying to do actually?